# Angular ngFor for an object

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to use ngFor to create a dropdown menu depending on my object key. For example

Component.ts

```
Drop_Down_Menu={1:[1,2,3],2:[3,4,5],3:[4,5,6]}
```

Component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Drop_Down_Menu[1]">
    <Label class="donation-label">{{item.value}}</Label>
</ng-container>
```

my intended output should be a drop-menu with values

```
1
2
3
```

Currently

I am getting

```
1,2,3
```

all in one row instead of in their own rows

Comment: <ng-container *ngFor="let item of Drop_Down_Menu[1]">
    <Label class="donation-label">{{item}}</Label>
</ng-container>

Comment: Item is not an object just a number, remove the .value part. Also your variable names of your object are not matching.

Comment: you need to write a nested ngfor here as your each item itself is a collection.

Comment: @Rishabh That did not work :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of Drop_Down_2_Stuff | keyvalue">
                        <div *ngIf="item.key==1">
                            <div *ngFor="let stuff of item.value">
                                {{stuff}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
```

@Rihabh thanks